# Should I use Postgresql or MySQL for a new project with Drizzle on the horizon?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, drizzle

Since Oracle has MySQL and now is working on [Drizzle](http://www.mycstubes.com/2011/06/is-mysql-dead.html), for a new project should I choose Postgres?  I need a free database and though I've always used MySQL in the past, I'm concerned about it now.  Drizzle isn't hosted in a lot of places like MySQL is.

update:  Found this here:  http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL

"PostgreSQL has a good reputation with Oracle developers, which is most certainly related to its much stricter and reliable approach, like that of Oracle. The difficulties and controversy around MariaDB, Drizzle and corporate takeovers have left many people re-considering their database strategy."

Comment: MySQL's not going anywhere. Oracle may own the DB now, but it's a GPL project and the source for the GPL versions will always be available. Oracle may let it wither and die, but there's a big enough user community to ensure that development will continue.

Comment: MySQL isn't going any where for a while and will probably always have a free option. Why are you concerned on using it?

Comment: Because I don't know that it will ever be the force that it once was.  Sure you can fork the project and keep up with it but it won't be what it used to be...or at least it's momentum seems to be lessened.

Comment: Just to make your choice even more difficult :) : MariaDB is an another MySQL based possibility. It looks quite viable (IMHO more so than Drizzle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL and Drizzle have different audiences and are also at different levels of maturity.  PostgreSQL focuses on logical correctness and expressiveness; where drizzle is much more oriented toward scalability.

A more meaningful metric is that PostgreSQL is available and stable and mature today; but drizzle is not.  If you can afford to hedge your project on an unreleased technology, and the purported benefits of using it fit particularly well with your projects goals, then it's a reasonable choice.

If you *need* your project to work for sure, favoring a proven back end technology is more prudent.